# Any visualization tools for Cassandra keyspaces?

Tags: cassandra, data-visualization

Are there any visualisation tools to cassandra keyspaces? Comming from the RDBMS world used to viewing table data and entries, are there any well know tools that can provide a 'table-like' view of keyspaces? GUI based would be great!

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there [are](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/FAQ#gui), also, you can try on cli? cassandra-cli with `show schema` or `describe`

- [chiton](https://github.com/driftx/chiton)
- [casandra-gui](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-gui/?redir=1)
- [Cassandra Cluster Admin](https://github.com/sebgiroux/Cassandra-Cluster-Admin)
- [helenos](https://github.com/tomekkup/helenos)

Comment: I created a version of cassandra-gui [here](https://github.com/libjack/cassandra-gui) to add support for all data types, including Composite types. Can add/update rows + columns.

Comment: And I used https://github.com/sebgiroux/Cassandra-Cluster-Admin as a first try. Was simple,elegant and took me 10 minutes to get it up and running.

Comment: I use cassandra-gui without any problem.

Comment: I'll add DBeaver to the list: http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/

Answer (score 3):

Check it out [Helenos](https://github.com/tomekkup/helenos#readme) - it's a simple web based tool